# How to hide form field in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I am new to opencart, i want to hide Address2 From registration form.
I tried more but not working.

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-address-2"><?php echo $entry_address_2; ?></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" name="address_2" value="<?php echo $address_2; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_address_2; ?>" id="input-address-2" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add class `hide` to `form-group` container

```
<div class="form-group hide">
```

In that way you hide it with label.

And this way is standard for opencart templates.

Answer (score 0):

Pass css property display:none in it like:

```
<input type="text" name="address_2" style="display:none;" value="<?php echo $address_2; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_address_2; ?>" id="input-address-2" class="form-control" />
```

It will hide the above input.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-address-2"><?php echo $entry_address_2; ?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" name="address_2" value="<?php echo $address_2; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_address_2; ?>" id="input-address-2" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

you can write display:none; in your div.